Can I reprogram a white noise machine?
I found this site when I just searched for a chip that's on the board of a white noise machine that I just bought. I'd really love to be able to edit the sound files, or even add my own. I'm using it for my tinnitus.  It's got 30 sounds but some are just wasted.
I see there's some programming pins etc. I'm a dab hand at micro soldering etc. I've been into electronics for years. I'd love to be able to have a go at this, I see the chip MIX2032 is the audio output chip, the TC4056A is for charging the battery. I think the 25vq64asig is the flash chip, but I can't find anything on the one in red (SZY84A2 U359G2412.)

GND Stands for ground, and is a basic concept in electrical  engineering. It's used as a reference point for voltage in circuits, and protects the circuit and the person working on it. In a USB  Micro-B SuperSpeed plug, the GND pin is black.
DM Stands for differential mode, and is a type of current that passes through a cable ferrite. In a USB interface, the DM pin is the
negative data terminal, and is also known as D–.
DP Stands for positive data terminal, and is also known as D+. In a USB Micro-B SuperSpeed plug, the DP pin is green.
V+ Stands for the voltage supplied by the USB host to power any connected peripheral. In a USB interface, the V+ pin is known as VBUS, and is pin 1. The VBUS wire carries a nominal 5V supply.

Is this possible?


Solder a USB cable to J1 and see what the device enumerates as then you plug it in.

We can't know if you or anyone else can modify it. Usually MCUs in products are locked for reading and further programming to prevent reverse-engineering and hacking. You might have more luck copying the design where you have a MCU which you can freely access and program to do anything you want.

Also, from where is that quote from? Is it perhaps output of some AI like ChatGPT? It looks like mishmash of concepts jumbled together without a real clue.

SZY84A is a sound/voice chip produced by Shenzhen. The datasheet is entirely in Chinese.
However translation of the product page does reveal the chip has a USB port, so it would make sense for those pins to be USB.
How it's programmed I don't know. Undoubtedly the flash will store some form of audio, however what format it's in is anyone's guess - the chip supports multiple codecs.

Oh wow! this is awesome, thanks so much for your input, both of you :)
So it's possible to read it, I have a USB To RS232 TTL UART PL2303HX Converter USB to COM Module Serial Cable Adapter and a FTDI Serial Adapter FT232RL FT232 TTL 5V 3.3V USB UART Programmer for ESP8266 do you think I could use one of these, any idea on what software I'd use?

Nice find. This is a pretty cool little chip, sadly I don't see any place to buy them in small quantities.

Oh I have them, I bought one of each from eBay

I would wire a USB cord directly to the pins on the PCB. Go through a cheap hub if you have doubts about your work. See what enumerates. It's possible the chip is an SOC which creates (or at least uses) a FAT file system on the flash chip, and it will show up as a flash drive, and you can back up the original file (perhaps an MP3) and then put your own file(s) in place using your PC.
I don't see any accessible MCU here for programming. There's some strapping and connections intended for (optional) connection from the Shenzhen Si Ze Yuan Technology SZY84A to an external MCU. You could wire those to an Arduino or whatever. There is the SOC SZY84A as @Tom found the datasheet for , an audio amplifier chip (the MIX2032) and a battery management chip (the TC4056A)
When there is an MCU present, the chip communicates with a simple serial protocol, as explained in the datasheet. The characters for serial port are 串口. The 串 character for serial is the same one used for a kabob and the 口 is the same character used for mouth.
Without an MCU the buttons shown the schematic come into play:

In order from top to bottom (not numerical order):
Play-Pause
Previous song/volume+  (short vs. long press)
Next song/volume-   (short vs. long press0
Volume keys
Long press to record, short press to stop recording
Play recording
Replay button
Stop key
Similar serial commands are available, as explained in the datasheet.
It's not clear to me if the thing will just start playing the first file over and over if you tie ADKEY to ground, but maybe.

If you can't follow the english manual for the serial port, write or call the OEM.
For any problems, suggestions or comments during the use, please contact 0755-26652552 or email to
SOC_support@socmcu.com
end update
It's an 8051-based Flash MCU, where the P/N may be decoded below.
A similar datasheet in English will guide you to the JTAG protocol that hopefully matches.
There are many other easy alternatives to make a white noise with a few simple chips for a random sequence or even use Audacity.exe to synth. anything. I would suggest the latter to create a wave file and upload it to flash. (if you know how) or upload it to your smartphone or use iOS background sounds of white noise, water stream, wind etc.

Source https://www.socmcu.com/upfile/SC92F84A3_84A2_84A1v0.1en.pdf

This isn't an answer to your question. This is a follow-up question to your original. Also how would this adapter help in any way, why do you ask? –
@Justme  Commented22 hours ago
This post is hidden. It was deleted 21 hours ago by Voltage Spike♦.
Sorry just having fun and asking questions, I get it though, I also didn't know how the forum works. when I made a reply and you deleted my post which was actually a question

I cannot delete your post. What is your problem with asking the OEM? I only told you how I would solve the issue.

Voltage Spike deleted my post my friend, not you

@MrInfelix - You said: "Voltage Spike deleted my post" Yes, one of my co-moderators correctly deleted a non-answer posted as an answer. "you deleted my post which was actually a question" Exactly - you posted a question in the space reserved for answers, so it was deleted as "Not An Answer" :( || This site is a Q&A site, not a traditional forum and it has different rules. Something posted as an answer must (try to) answer the original question & not ask questions. Since you asked the question, only use the "Your Answer" entry box below if you have fully solved your own question.

If we waited for answers to be verified we would find many need to be likewise deleted until the proven. In the end each contributes helpful clues  but more parameters makes this complex protocol difficult for a simple answer site
